# ArrayFormula SWITCH SEQUENCE

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

My **apologies**, no link to a spreadsheet (its a big one). Was hoping an expert could give some anecdotal advice why the first formula works and the second does not.

Specifically, I can narrow it down to SEQUENCE function (if I remove SEQUENCE there is no #VALUE! error). All range names are columns except for MaxOneTerms which is a number.

Following using IF works fine.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(OneStep)),,
    TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
      IF(SEQUENCE(1,MaxOneTerms,1)>OneTerms,,
        IF(OneType="Geo",
          ROUND(OneStart*OneStep^SEQUENCE(1,MaxOneTerms,0)),
          IF(OneType="Ari",
            ROUND(OneStart+OneStep*SEQUENCE(1,MaxOneTerms,0)),
            "OneType-ERR"
          )
        )&","
      )
    ),,100000)))
  )
)
```

The following with SWITCH (replacing IF for readability) returns #VALUE! for each value.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(OneStep)),,
    TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
      IF(SEQUENCE(1,MaxOneTerms,1)>OneTerms,,
        SWITCH(OneType,
          "Geo",ROUND(OneStart*OneStep^SEQUENCE(1,MaxOneTerms,0)),
          "Ari",ROUND(OneStart+OneStep*SEQUENCE(1,MaxOneTerms,0)),
          "OneType-ERR"
        )&","
      )
    ),,100000)))
  )
)
```

The following with SWITCH, but without SEQUENCE executes (but obviously not the expected values).

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(OneStep)),,
    TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
      IF(SEQUENCE(1,MaxOneTerms,1)>OneTerms,,
        SWITCH(OneType,
          "Geo",ROUND(OneStart*OneStep),
          "Ari",ROUND(OneStart+OneStep),
          "OneType-ERR"
        )&","
      )
    ),,100000)))
  )
)
```

---

Edit 1: (linked added below).
Sheet "SeriesX" column "S" row 3. Please ignore the rest.
I've tried variants in Sheet "SeriesX2" F3,G3,H3

google [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P7Jq_h4V4mGOZN6eqLdDfFs8p9FjsD-k__I09Eeoy0w/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Seems crazy to try to parse out a formula like that without a sheet

Comment: Also SWITCH() used to work in an arrayformula like that but changes were made about a year ago that changed that capability.  Try writing a super simple SWITCH() that does something similar and you should see it not work.

Comment: I agree with MattKing. Dropping a formula like this (with named ranges no less) and no spreadsheet to reference is like calling a car mechanic and saying, "My car isn't working. It's making a weird noise. I can't tell you what the make or model is, and I can't bring it in, but what's wrong with it and how can I fix it?"

Comment: Again and first, my apologies on linked sheet. After reviewing the documentation I'm inclined to agree with @MattKing - SWITCH is not made to work in this environment. I also found that IFS does not work either. So its nested IF() all the way. I guess, this might be useful to the next person who comes along.

Comment: @RiyazMansoor looking at your formula i believe I can do it without a nested IF(), just need some data and a goal! :)

Comment: @MattKing link to a sheet added. The objective is to add more types to "Geo" metric, "Ari" thmetic, so a readable formula would be sorely desired.

Comment: @RiyazMansoor Kind of difficult to tell the goal of column S.  It also looks like Column S is only one middle step towards the real goal?

Comment: @MattKing That is correct. Eventual goals are many. But column S in of itself - is also a goal.